# Why is this spitting out the content in the wrong place?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

On my WordPress page I have like

```
<div>
   <!-- bunch of HTML in here -->
</div>
[bottomform text="blah blah"]
```

where the shortcode `bottomform` calls a function that simply `echo`es HTML like

```
function get_bottom_form ( $atts )
{
   echo "...";
}
```

However, when the page is rendered the order is flipped, that is, the stuff `echo`ed by the function is coming out before.

Why could that be?

Comment: could you show the output? did you see the output html code or only the view on browser? I mean.. it can be a css problem floatting the content, for instance.

Comment: I think your shortcode handler should return content rather than echoing it directly.